# Explanation of a step in a proof of Steinhaus' Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Disclaimer**: I understand this theorem has been discussed before. I am not looking for a proof however, just a clarification of a mysterious step.

I was reading a proof of the following version of Steinhaus' Theorem, and got stuck on one step:

> **Theorem (Steinhaus)**: Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $m(E)>0$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the set $E-E$
>   contains an interval around zero.
>
> **Proof**: By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, or, equivalently, by the definition of a Lebesgue point, there exists an interval $I$
>   such that
>
> $$m(I\cap E) \geq (1-\epsilon)\,m(I).$$
>
> If the result were not true, there would exist a sequence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ with $x_n \not \in E-E$. Take $n$ large enough that $|x_n|<\epsilon\, m(I)$. Then $x_n +E \subset \mathbb {R} \setminus E$, but
>
> $$\mathbf{m(I\cap (x_n+E))\geq (1-3\epsilon)\,m(I)}$$
>
> **(since Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations.)** Since $E$ and $\mathbb R \setminus E$ are disjoint, this is a contradiction.

The part I am having difficulty with is in bold characters. I believe it follows from the following:

\begin{align*}
m(I\cap (x_n+E)) & = m(x_n+(I-x_n)\cap E) \\
& = m((I-x_n)\cap E) \\
& \geq m(I) - 2|x_n| - m(I \setminus E) \\
& \geq (1-3\epsilon)\,m(I)
\end{align*}

Is this correct? If not, could you point out the correct steps? Thanks!

**Note**: For the sake of completeness,

$$E-E:=\{x-y:\ x,y\in E \}.$$

Comment: Is that a typo $E-E$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant it is not. in general the theorem holds for $A+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both o nonzero measure. $E-E$ is a special case.

Comment: Ah you mean $E-E=\{a-b\mid a,b\in E\}$.  I thought it meant set minus in which case it would be $\emptyset$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes. I added a remark to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\mu (I \cap (x + E) ) = \mu ( (I- x) \cap E) \ge \mu ( I \cap E) - \mu ( (I \backslash (I - x) ) \cap E)\ge \mu ( I \cap E) - \mu(I \backslash (I - x) ) $$
and $\mu(I \backslash (I - x) )= |x|$ if $I$ fixed and $x$ small enough.

${\bf Added:}$ In fact, this seems to be true: if $\mu(I \cap E) \ge (\frac{1}{2} + \delta) |I| $ then $E - E$ will contain the interval $(-2\delta|I|, 2 \delta|I|)$.

Comment: This looks good! But I am not sure where (in the proof I posted), a factor of $2 \epsilon$ came from. According to your calculation, only one factor of $\epsilon$ is introduced from $I \setminus (I-x)$

Comment: @GaussTheBauss:    the factor of $2\epsilon$ is perhaps from $\mu( I \Delta (I-x))$. But $\mu(I \backslash (I-x))$ does the trick already.

Comment: Do you mean by $\delta$ symmetric difference ($\Delta$)? If so, Then I see what you are saying.

Comment: Nevermind! you caught that :) Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: You are welcome! A nice result. If you use the fact that $\mu(E) = \inf_{U = \overset{\circ}{U}\supset A} \mu (U)$ and every open subset is a disjoint union of intervals you can find such an $I$ by hand

Comment: That is very interesting; never thought about that. What I find most fascinating about this result is its generalization to Haar measures.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: Oh that's nice, never thought of that. I wonder how would the proof work, since we may not have those nice subsets like the intervals. Ah, maybe some regularity of the measure would work, to squeeze it between a compact and an open. OK, have to think about that.

Comment: Yes. I believe what is crucial is invariance under he group operation. In $(\mathbb {R},+)$, it's Lebesgue measure. In $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \},\cdot)$, the measure is $\frac {dx}{x}$.