# Convergence of $\exp(c_n it)$ for all $t$ in a set with positive Lebesgue measure implies convergence of $c_n$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, analysis

Suppose $(c_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $e^{c_nit}$ converges for every $t\in E$ and $E$ has positive Lebesgue measure. I want to show $c_n \to c<\infty$.

Motivation: This is an exercise in Kai Lai Chung's probability text. It's useful because it's easier to show $e^{c_nit}$ converges than to argue directly about $c_n$. In particular, letting $S_n = X_1+\dots+X_n$ being the sum of i.i.d. random variables, if $S_n$ converges weakly, we can show it also converges almost surely by first showing that $e^{S_n it}$ converges almost surely, and then using the lemma to conclude.

As a hint, Chung says to argue that $c_n$ cannot converge to an infinite limit, and that it cannot have two subsequences which converge to different numbers.

My attempt: Using the dominated convergence theorem, I considered
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E e^{c_n it}\,d\lambda(t) = \int_E \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{c_nit}\,d\lambda(t)$$
And I tried to find some sort of reason why it could not be the case that $c_n$ does not converge, but I can't see it. I also feel that because the convergence happens on a set with positive Lebesgue measure, it seems like quite a strong hypothesis. For $e^{i\theta}$ is periodic, and if the convergence is on say a countable set, then clearly it's not true. But I don't know how to leverage the convergence on $E$ besides considering the integral, which did not lead anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $E-E$ contains an interval around $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known that if $E$ has positive Lebesgue measure then $E-E=\{x-y:x,y 
\in E\}$ contains $[-r,r]$ for some $r>0$. See: [Explanation of a step in a proof of Steinhaus' Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589079/explanation-of-a-step-in-a-proof-of-steinhaus-theorem)

Now $e^{i(c_n-c_m)t} =e^{ic_nt}\overline {e^{ic_mt}} \to 1$ as $n,m \to \infty$. Integrating from $-r$ ro $r$ we get $\frac {\sin (r(c_n-c_m))} {c_n-c_n} \to 1$. Use properties if $\sin x$ to conlude that $c_n-c_m \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$.

Comment: Is the second $c_n$ supposed to be a $c_m$? For the people wondering why $e^{ic_n t} \overline{e^{ic_m t}} \rightarrow 1$. Recall that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{ic_n t} =: a_t $ exists for $t\in E$ and so $1 = \vert e^{i c_n t} \vert \rightarrow \vert a_t \vert$. Thus, we get $e^{ic_n t} \overline{e^{ic_m t}} \rightarrow a_t \overline{a_t} = \vert a_t \vert^2 =1$.

Comment: Aaand before I forget... nice answer :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your comments.