# Convergence of characteristics functions

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

**I have this problem:**
If $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of real numbers and $(e^{i u a_n})_n$ converges to finite limit $g(u)$ for all $u\in I\subset\mathbb{R}$. Show that $(a_n)_n$ converges.

I tried to prove using Levy's continuity theorem, but the problem is the continuity of the limit of $(e^{i u a_n})_n$ at $u=0$. Someone can give me any hint for this part of the continuity ?.

This is an exercise (Chapter 8 Ex4) of the Book “real analysis and probability ” by Robert Ash.

Comment: This question has been answered many times.

Comment: I searched this question here and I didn’t find anything :(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593326/convergence-of-expc-n-it-for-all-t-in-a-set-with-positive-lebesgue-measur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By dominated convergence theorem, the following convergence holds for each $b<c$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_b^c e^{iua_n}du=\int_b^cg(u)du.
$$
Fix $b,c$ such that $b<c$ and $\int_b^cg(u)du\neq 0$ (such $b,c$ exist, otherwise, $g$ would have an integral that vanishes over every interval hence would be identically zero, which is not possible, since $\lvert g(u)\rvert=1$). Then express
$
a_n\int_b^ce^{ia_nu}du
$ as a constant times $e^{ica_n}-e^{icb_n}$. For $n$ large enough, you can divide by $\int_b^ce^{ia_nu}du$ and derive the wanted convergence.

Comment: What is the reason for fix $b$? I mean, initially why cannot I supposed that the function is distinct of 0?

Comment: @DanielStivenMartinezCastill I added more detail on this part.

Comment: Thank you, I have just proved my problem using your hint.

Comment: Good! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: A duplicate: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593326/convergence-of-expc-n-it-for-all-t-in-a-set-with-positive-lebesgue-measur/4593393#4593393